Libraries override jquery_ui_accordion
How can i override jquery_ui_accordion? I can't figure out how.
libraries-override:      
  # Does not work?
    jquery_ui_accordion/accordion:
      css:
        component:
          assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/accordion.css: false


The CR (https://www.drupal.org/node/3067969) mentions that jquery.ui/themes/base/accordion.css: false should work, but it didn't seem to.
I decided to set the path relative to the root.
libraries-override:
  jquery_ui_accordion/accordion:
    css:
      component:
        /modules/contrib/jquery_ui/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/accordion.css: false

